# Pandas, table filling, python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How do I add the first purchase date by user_id in the entire dateframe?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atRjd.png)

```
first_df=orders.loc[orders['ship_mode'] == "First"] #First - first purchase
first_df
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ticR.png)

I found the date of the first user purchase, but I don't know how to add it to the whole table.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough rep to comment and there's probably a better way than this but could you create a blank column, then iterate through the dataframe row by row?

```
first_orders.set_index('id')

orders['first order date'] = ""
for num, row in orders.iterrows():
    orders.loc[num, 'first order date'] = first_orders.loc[row['id'], 'order_date']
```